# Centering image in the middle of page with Jade and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

I just started using Jade and Bootstrap and have run into a snag. I am trying to center an image in the middle of my index.jade. I was able to get it horizontally centered, but not vertically centered. Below is my index.jade and a image of what it currently looks like.

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
a.container
a.row
img.center-block(src= "images/logo.png")
```

Current screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a custom class, like this:

```
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

And:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 center">
        <div>Center</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
```

for the element that you want to center vertically.